# Repeating filtering task with vba

Tags: excel, vba

How would I repeat filtering/saving task with input value stored in smart table? For example,

```
    Sheets("Data").Select
    
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ManualUpdate = True
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Parent Supplier 2").ClearAllFilters
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Parent Supplier 2").CurrentPage = _
                X
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ManualUpdate = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").SaveData = False

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs File_location
```

In this case, how would I set X as looping so that it would repeat the process for each value listed in smart table? Or is the only way to go about this repeating the vba code for each items that I have to filter and save?

Thank you,
Jununu

Comment: `For Each X In ....`?

Comment: X as value I'd like to filter. I have multiple values I am trying to filter/save and didn't know if I could use looping function to repeat the process instead of rewriting the code 15 times

Comment: Yes you can loop... I'm giving you the start.

Comment: Hi BigBen, how would I be able to loop this?

Comment: I don't know where you're getting `X` from. I don't know what you mean by "smart table."

Comment: Sorry about that. What I meant by X is Dim X as Variant  and X = "Filter item" but the items will be stored in table. So for example, Table with data : Microsoft, Salesforce, Amazon, Etc... will be used to filter data by Microsoft, Salesforce, Amazon, etc. I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it but something that I had in mind.

Comment: Then loop over the table range... plenty of examples online on how to do that.